# toshiba recovery disc windows 8 os

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, toshiba-laptop

So i have had a friend ask me to look at there toshiba satellite c855-28u because its not working even using the recovery disc form which i have discovered that doesn't appear to be working as it is getting stuck at 1% on the clean install option and no other options worked cuase clearly some one has had a party with this hard drive.

Now i have just learned about uefi gpt from another post on this site which was a excellent answer by Rod Smith and realised that the issue is also with the recovery disc not just the hard drive as i have put in a new hard drive and im still having the same issue now i am trying to install from a windows 8 disc and i have set the bios to allow for a non uefi boot disc and having an issue with the separte partitions telling me its gpt and cannot install "joy".

so im doing a disc wipe following the post i read could somebody please tell me how this is ment to pan out from here ? and exactly what i should do ?

edit : got a disc wipe error telling me device I/O error trying a restart

many thanks

Dan